# Which investment should I make?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I recently started Assassin's Creed Brotherhood - and I see I now have the ability to make "investments" in shops, which seems to involve and upfront outlay of cash, and sort of a "dividend" system of randomly getting a return on that investment.  Its been a while, but I don't recall this system from AC II.

It seems like there are a million shops, and they all seem to also have a "risk" rating, which I assume is somehow related.  I'm a little overwhelmed by all of the choices, and it seems I can only be "invested" in one shop at a time (unless I misunderstood something).  So which shop (or kind of shop) is the best bet for investment?

Comment: You're referring to the _Global Economy_ for all shops I presume. From my experience, deciding in which shops to "invest" in doesn't matter at all. You're going to be making (easy) money no matter what you do. Even if it isn't a particularly big profit, it won't matter still, you'll soon have more money than you can ever need.

Comment: I guess it is the Global Economy, yes.  "Invest" is an option that appears in the main shop menu, along with "Sell", "Buy" etc.  I can look up the exact text if necessary.  The game warns that I can invest in only one shop, and provides risk levels for each "district" like "Safe" or "High Risk" etc.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, I can confirm it is the "Rome Global Economy" that I am referencing, which you can access when looking at the map.  There is actually both a "Risk Factor" and a "Popularity".  It's good to know that I'll be rolling in money.  I guess I could accept MPelletier's answer on those grounds, unless you have a more direct answer.

Comment: What is this 'investing' mechanic?  Have I missed it?  I just completed memory sequence 5.  I have plenty of dough rolling in as I have renovated most of the shops and will get to the landmarks last.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The economics of Brotherhood are much simpler than they seem and within hours you'll be submerged in cash.

You want to make sure you invest in banks early on. They will carry your money earned every 20 minutes, but when the banks are full, they don't keep piling it anymore. You don't want that nagging you all the time.

Because landmarks are sometimes larger investments, keep them for later, you'll be able to buy more buildings (blacksmiths and doctors first, tailors and art merchants last) and enjoy the rebates right away.

Don't neglect secret passages. Those will come in handy and they're cheap.

Comment: I am certain he's talking about the global economy, not just normal renovations. There's no risk involved in renovating a place.

Comment: While true, I have found renovating the shops, banks, and secret tunnels (or warp pipes) give the best return.  I would make the landmarks the last real estate to purchase.